# Install4j I cannot create a simple symbolic link to the users home directory Applications for mac DMG

Tags: macos, symlink, install4j

Im trying to add a symlink target as "Configure Additional Files in the DMG" in install4j.
I set the Symlink target to "~/Applications" which is the syntax that works fine if doing "ln -s" from the command line.
I set the "Name in DMG" to "Applications".
But it doesnt work, I get some kind of folder that doesnt work.It looks like a symlink because it has an arrow on it but when I click on it I get "the operation cant be completed because the original item for Applications cant be found".

Maybe there is a compiler variable I should use?

All Im trying to achieve is to have the Users Applications folder inthe install so they can simply drag the package into it like for many other application installers.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232720/using-in-symlink-target-or-making-a-symlink-with-a-variable

Comment: If tilde "~" cant be used, how can I refer to the users home directory in the install4j symlink?

Comment: I don't think you can. You would need variables in a symlink target which is not supported by macOS.

Comment: Ive seen other installers that have the Users "/User/<me>/Applications" folder as a symlink in the mounted DMG so they can just drag the app across.  I wonder how they do that

Comment: If you find such an installer, can you check by doing `ls -la` in the mounted DMG?